# SIGSEGV Error on Dynamic Programming - CodeChef

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, segmentation-fault

Hope you all are having a great day!

I love programming, but these past days I am having sleepless nights, with CodeChef always returning SIGSEGV errors on my Dynamic Programming solutions.

I am solving [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS) question right now. Here's the question -

> In Byteland they have a very strange monetary system. Each Bytelandian
>   gold coin has an integer number written on it. A coin n can be
>   exchanged in a bank into three coins: n/2, n/3 and n/4. But these
>   numbers are all rounded down (the banks have to make a profit). You
>   can also sell Bytelandian coins for American dollars. The exchange
>   rate is 1:1. But you can not buy Bytelandian coins. You have one gold
>   coin. What is the maximum amount of American dollars you can get for
>   it?
>
> Input
>
> The input will contain several test cases (not more than 10). Each
>   testcase is a single line with a number n, 0 <= n <= 1 000 000 000. It
>   is the number written on your coin. Output
>
> For each test case output a single line, containing the maximum amount
>   of American dollars you can make. Example
>
> Input: 12 2
>
> Output: 13 2 You can change 12 into 6, 4 and 3, and then change these
>   into $6+$4+$3 = $13. If you try changing the coin 2 into 3 smaller
>   coins, you will get 1, 0 and 0, and later you can get no more than $1
>   out of them. It is better just to change the 2 coin directly into $2.

Now I know that it's very easy. And I did get stuck initially when I was declaring a big 10^9 integer long array (Over 1GB of memory..whoo!), but coming back to my senses - I decided to do memoization till 10001, and after that simple recursion. But still - I am making a mistake, and it's giving SIGSEGV error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

long long n[100001];

long long calc(long long x) {
    if (x < 10001) {
        if(n[x] != 0) return n[x];
        n[x] = max(x, calc(x/2) + calc(x/3) + calc(x/4));
        return n[x];
    }
    else return max(x, calc(x/2) + calc(x/3) + calc(x/4));
}

int main() {
    memset(n, 0, sizeof(n));
    n[1] = 1;
    n[2] = 2;
    n[3] = 3;
    n[4] = 4;
    n[5] = 5;
    n[6] = 6;
    for (int i = 7; i < 10001; i++)
        n[i] = calc(i);
    int t = 10;
    while (t--) {
        long long c;
        scanf("%lld", &c);
        printf("%lld\n", calc(c));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have solved some previous questions too - and all of them gave me this error once or twice. I know this error means that I am trying to access memory that hasn't been allocated, but what is wrong in my approach that I always get this error?

Comment: Which line is the SEGV happening on?

Comment: @Barmar The solution is being accepted on other online compliers, but the CodeChef complier (ie. the website where the question is posted) is giving SEGV without the line number.

Comment: Maybe it's a stack overflow in the recursion.

Comment: Does it only happen when `c` is large?

Comment: @Barmer Thanks a lot for your reply. Maybe, that's the case. But I have checked for the largest value of 'c' (as given in the question), yet it is working in other compliers. Is my approach to the problem correct?

Comment: @BrahmnoorSingh *yet it is working in other compilers* -- You do not know what the test data is used by the "other compilers".  If you do know the test data used, please post it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul! Thanks a lot for your reply. I am learning new stuff each day! I certainly don't know the test cases being used by the Online Judges - and I was kind of immature in suggesting that the code is working as intended on other compilers because I wasn't thinking of the corner cases. 0 was the key. Got it, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is with the corner case n=0.

calc(0) recurses indefinitely because 0<10001 and n[0]=0. You need to add the terminating condition that calc(0)=0.

Takeaways:

- Always check your programming competition solutions on corner cases.
- Always ensure that your recursion does not result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ohhh damn! Believe me - I had thought about 0 - I had - but then I got kind of diverted! How did I miss it? Anyway - it is such a huge relief - and certainly a nice lesson to learn. Thanks, buddy! High five!